# Owl Carousel not working on installation, even when following guides

Tags: html

I have read the documentation and setup over and over but I can not seem to get owl carousel to work properly.
Below I have a simple HTML file containing what should be enough to have a simple owl carousel section going, but it does not work.

If anyone knows why it does not work or if I can get a push in the right direction, that would help tremendously.
Thanks!

Edit:
Here is the website for the Owl Carousel (plugin?): https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Owls</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5 ml-5">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">1</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">2</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">3</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">4</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">5</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">6</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">7</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">8</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">9</div>
            <div class="ml-2 mr-2" style="background-color: #ddd;">10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script>$('owl-carousel').owlCarousel();</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what, specifically, is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$('owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
```

To:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(); // Note the . (dot) in the jquery selector
```

The selector in your code selects the element with the tag as owl-carousel. But it needs to select the element with class owl-carousel.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

That does make a bit more sense. 
However, even upon changing the . in the jquery selector, nothing has changed. I am expecting the 10 divs created to be in a row, scrolling from left to right, but as things look now all the divs are stacked on top of each other. 

Here is a video for reference on what I would like the outcome to be:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbXLkhIfSTQ

Thank you for your quick response and help so far

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. Fix your query selector `'.owl-carousel'` instead of `'owl-carousel'`

```
 <script>$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();</script>
```

2. Check to make sure your are linking your stylesheets correctly. Depending on how you are including the CSS, this step may be slightly different. I just downloaded it from [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html), extracted it, copied the `dist/` folder to my project, and renamed it `owlcarousel/`.

My file tree:

```
.
├── index.html
├── owlcarousel
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── ajax-loader.gif
│   │   ├── owl.carousel.css
│   │   ├── owl.carousel.min.css
│   │   ├── owl.theme.default.css
│   │   ├── owl.theme.default.min.css
│   │   ├── owl.theme.green.css
│   │   ├── owl.theme.green.min.css
│   │   └── owl.video.play.png
│   ├── owl.carousel.js
│   └── owl.carousel.min.js
```

So, I simply changed `href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css"` to `href="owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"` to match my file structure

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
```